# I want to SetState the items of a child component from the child component to the parent component

Tags: reactjs

I want to expand the number in the child component and change the count state of the parent component. How can I change the number in the child component to the count state of the parent component from the parent component?

For example, I want to update the count state of the parent component to 12 when the parent component presses the button labeled 12 created by the child component.

Parent Component

```
class Parent extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            count: ""
        }
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <Child />
        )
    }
}
```

Child Component

```
class Child extends Component {
    render() {
        const number = ["12", "14", "15", "16", "22", "35", "6", "92", "47", "32", "75", "67"]
        return (
            <div>
                {(() => {
                    const items = [];
                    for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                        items.push(<button>{number[i]}</button>)
                    };
                    return <>{items}</>;
                })()}
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass a function from parent component to child component which will be called from child component when button will be clicked,
and update parent's state in that function
eg
Parent component:

```
class Parent extends Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        count: ""
    }
}
render() {
    return (
        <Child onButtonClick={(number) => this.setState({count: this.state.count + number})}/>
    )
}
}
```

Child Component:

```
class Child extends Component {
render() {
    const number = ["12", "14", "15", "16", "22", "35", "6", "92", "47", "32", "75", "67"]
    return (
        <div>
            {(() => {
                const items = [];
                for (let i = 1; i <= 12; i++) {
                    items.push(<button onClick={() => this.props.onButtonClick(number[i])}>{number[i]}</button>)
                };
                return <>{items}</>;
            })()}
        </div>
    )
}
}
```